Order lines by depth from center
I'm working with projections (from 2d to 1d), and right now I'm trying to implement a z-buffer. Essentially I have a bunch of non-overlapping segments (all with y>0) and a center point (with y<0). I know it's possible to order all of the segments such that if segment A > B, then there's no rays from the center that intersect A and then B (A is "behind" B). 
I want to map each line to a real number, keeping this order property. How should I define that function? 
Edit: I gave it a bit of thought and found out it's not possible; the relation A > B, for some segments A and B depends on the other segments present, and cannot be assigned a unique number

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What is the ordering on segments? A picture might help.
